# Contact point of object hitting a trigger collider

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have an object that's target-like in nature (i.e. hitting the bullseye calls one function, middle another, and outer ring a third).  I have another object hitting that target, and I'm trying to determine what part of the trigger was hit in OnTriggerEnter.  I tried the line below but it seems to be giving me the contact point in world space.  How can I get the coordinates of the contact point for the object hit, to determine what function to call?

```
Vector3 localVector = other.gameObject.GetComponent<Collider>().ClosestPointOnBounds(transform.position);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Transform.InverseTransformPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.InverseTransformPoint.html)

```
var localClosestPoint = transform.InverseTransformPoint(closestPoint);
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, using the line I provided as closestPoint.  I'm still seeing some weird coordinates coming back though, including negative values for X and Z.  Is this just because of how a coordinate grid works? If so maybe I could then take the Vector3.Distance of localClosestPoint from Vector3.Zero to see how far from the center of the target the collision point was?

Comment: Why do you think it's weird? Negative x means the point is at the right side, and negative z means the point is at the back side.